# How to improve Tesseract.js on simple case with a webcam

Tags: javascript, browser, ocr, webcam-capture, tesseract.js

I'm trying to improve the quality of the character recognition with OCR using Tesseract.js and my webcam (reading the name on my identity card).

Though Tesseract 4.0 handles my case much better than tesseract.js (ported from 3.04), I still think it should be possible to get usable results - if I could just figure out where to tweak the options correctly!

So far I haven't really managed to improve anything beyond setting the correct language (including the special characters. Do you have any suggestions for improvement?

My best configuration so far seems to be simply `{ lan: 'dan' }`, with which I get consistently good results on numbers (a confidence around 80%), but a name like Mads Wårlich keeps getting read as mm, MW and other similar unusable matches.

I have tried different values of psm, and even user specific word file input (which doesn't seem to be supported), I've also considered trying to build a new set of training data because the font might be weird but it seems a lot of work for something that might not make a difference.

[image: bad quality truncated name from webcam capture]

(The image is truncated, since I'd prefer not to include my full name here, but it illustrates the quality and type of image I'm working on.)

Do you have any good suggestions for what I could do to improve my results in a case like this?